# OK button in Alert Box

Tags: javascript, button, alert

I need to put an alert box with the message “Welcome!” after every 5 seconds and will only exit
after 5 times of clicking the OK button. Is that possible?

Comment: Yes, you can achieve it by using a `prompt` https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/prompt and `setInterval` (https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/JavaScript/Asynchronous/Timeouts_and_intervals)

Comment: setInterval(function() { alert("Welcome!"); }, 5000)

Comment: that's my code when alert box will appear but i need now the ok button to be clicked 5 times in order to exit

Comment: You can fake the behavior by reopening the prompt as soon as it's closed if it hasn't been 5 times. Otherwise, you'll need to use a modal library, or make your own custom prompt (with HTML and CSS, not a native one). Also, who do you hate so badly that you want to destroy their life with this? (fortunately, most browsers ask the user whether they want to block any further prompts)

Comment: alert is a blocking code and it would be difficult to get a hold on the event of the alert box ok button click, so you can probably use the following code https://jsfiddle.net/u9htL0w2/

Comment: it's working but after I clicked the ok button 5 times, the greeting doesn't appear anymore, it should be appear again after 5 seconds

Answer (score 0):

#### Sumit's answer does work

I have turned it into a snippet to run here on Stack Overflow itself, and added numbers to the "Welcome" message, so you can follow its progress through the 5 clicks.

```js
const callWelcome = () => {
  alert('Welcome 1');
  alert('Welcome 2');
  alert('Welcome 3');
  alert('Welcome 4');
  alert('Welcome 5');
}

setTimeout(callWelcome, 5000);
```

I am confident this will work for you, because it is here on this site. If it doesn't, please indicate what "Welcome" message you are seeing, i.e. what number?

#### More closely match what you asked for

From my reading of your questions, you want a 5 second delay BEFORE the first alert, but then a NEW 5 second delay after closing the first alert, before opening the next alert, and so on. If so, this will do the trick.

```js
setTimeout(() => {
  alert('Welcome 1');
  setTimeout(() => {
    alert('Welcome 2');
    setTimeout(() => {
      alert('Welcome 3');
      setTimeout(() => {
        alert('Welcome 4');
        setTimeout(() => {
          alert('Welcome 5');
        }, 5000);
      }, 5000);
    }, 5000);
  }, 5000);
}, 5000);
```

#### So from your comment now, I realise you mean it should keep going round that loop?

It was not clear in your question, I am afraid. I now think you meant to say, "after 5 seconds, there is a welcome message, which you have to click 5 times to make it go away, and after that, after a 5 second delay, it reappears, and so on."

```js
function fivefoldMessage() {
  alert('Welcome 1');
  alert('Welcome 2');
  alert('Welcome 3');
  alert('Welcome 4');
  alert('Welcome 5');
  setTimeout(fivefoldMessage, 5000)
}

setTimeout(fivefoldMessage, 5000)
```

Comment: all the codes are correct but after the ok button clicked 5 times, the welcome message need to reappear after 5 seconds